# Getting errors while trying to do npm install on package.json

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm trying to do `npm install` for setting up an Angular project, but am running into these errors.  I am on mac and trying to open up a relatively old project, which is most likely the reason I'm running into the issues that I'm having.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.2
npm ERR! Found: typescript@3.5.3
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   dev typescript@"~3.5.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev || >=3.0.0-dev || >= 3.1.0-dev || >= 3.2.0-dev" from tslint@5.15.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/tslint
npm ERR!     dev tslint@"~5.15.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (tsutils)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer typescript@">=4.8.2 <5.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">=4.8.2 <5.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried doing `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps` but they both give me several vulnerabilities.  I also tried playing around downgrading node versions but to no avail.
I looked in the package.json version and located "@types/node": "~8.9.4", and from my what I've found is a specified dependency for the project, and tried downgrading to that version.  All that did was make it incredibly slow and eventually left me with errors.
Here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.2",
    "apollo-angular": "^4.2.1",
    "apollo-angular-link-http": "^1.11.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
    "deep-copy-ts": "^0.5.0",
    "graphql": "^14.7.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "ts-deepcopy": "^0.1.4",
    "tslib": "^1.13.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

[image: angular-cli version]

Here are the versions when i run `ng version' in my terminal.  I've just started working with front-end development so some input would be appreciated.

Edit:
Did robert's suggestion, got following error.

Attempt 2
[image]
[image]

Comment: change line with `"typescript": "~3.5.3"` to `"typescript": "~4.9.4"`, delete `node_modules` dir and `package-lock.json` file and try again `npm i`

Comment: updated the post with your suggestion

Comment: change this `"@angular/core": "^8.2.14",` to `"@angular/core": "^15.2.2",` same as before delete above dir and file and do `npm i`

Comment: updated post again

Comment: Revert to your original package.json and then try running `npx npm-check-updates`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This Problem is due to Having an Angular Version but not all npm packages are in support to the current version and many other deprecated functionalities.

```
npm install --force
```

It will download all the packages with their versions from **package.json** and make sures it will run the project when using

```
npm run start
```

To only download specified versions packages

```
npm ci --force
```

To fix the issue once you installed all the packaage.json if any problem arsies then use

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

New to SO otherwise I'd leave a comment instead, but if you're going to take the others' suggestions for updating your Angular and TypeScript deps, I think you really should only need `apollo-angular @apollo/client graphql` in order to get Apollo Client up and running. The piecemeal packages are all fairly outdated but probably would've worked fine on the older Angular versions.

`@apollo/client` is really where the magic happens now, and your operation, graphql tagging, HTTP Link, and most other imports just come straight from `apollo-angular`.

That being said, I've never tried to use the piecemeal packages with newer versions of Angular/React, but older TypeScript versions have definitely hated me! Also make sure to grab `@graphql-codegen` and associated options packages for stricter operation typing! Hope this helps :)